# Is dropping water from a cup in a dry bucket an incompressible flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm learning hydrodynamics by googling stuff so forgive me if the question is super simple.

Imagine that I'm holding a cup of water, which I proceed to drop in a bucket laying next to my feet. The water will splash, and after some movement it will spread across the bottom of the bucket forming a thin layer.

From my poor understanding, this flow should be a *compressible flow*. After all, the water is spreading across the bucket floor so the divergence should be greater than zero. I assume this would also be true in all scales, so "small packets" of water will also spread themselves across the space, each occupying more space than they did a few seconds before.

Nonetheless, every reference I found seem to state that water can be treated as an incompressible flow with the exception of very extreme conditions (under extreme pressure, next to the speed of sound, etc.).

What am I missing? How come water continues to behave as incompressible fluid, when it is clearly changing density and it's molecules are spreading through a larger area (which I understand means diverging)?

Comment: Does the volume of water change?

Comment: No, let's assume all the water that was in the cup reaches the bottom of the bucket.

Comment: Then by definition, the flow is incompressible.  If you track every small parcel of mass in the liquid, even though it deforms in this process, its volume remains constant.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm seeing my mistake here. I think I forgot volumes are 3D, and I focused on the each parcel is occupying a larger area of the bottom of the bucket so it gave me the impression they were increasing in "volume". You pointing out the volume remains the same made me realize the issue. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I figured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] when it is clearly changing density [...]

The shape the water is in has nothing to do with its density. It is changing shape, not density. Fill a cube of 1 m side length with water. Now put the same water in a cube with 10 m side length. The water will fill the larger cube only 1 cm high and is spread out over a much larger area. However, the volume is the same as before, the weight is the same as before, hence the density did not change, meaning it is incompressible.